# OVS bridge not receiving all packets from a Physical port

Tags: openstack

In a two OVS-DPDK compute node environment, im trying to forward/mirror one of the VM traffic from compute1 to compute2 through vxlan tunnel (userspace).

Im getting all the mirrored packets at the compute2's additional physical card ens1f1, but the same amount packets are not visible at the ovs-bridge.

```
ovs-vsctl --may-exist add-br br-phy \
    -- set Bridge br-phy datapath_type=netdev \
    -- br-set-external-id br-phy bridge-id br-phy \
    -- set bridge br-phy fail-mode=standalone \
         other_config:hwaddr=48:df:37:7e:c2:08

ovs-vsctl --timeout 10 add-port br-phy ens1f1
ip addr add 172.28.41.101/24 dev br-phy
ip link set br-phy up
ip addr flush dev ens1f1 2>/dev/null
ip link set ens1f1 up
```

I attached ens1f1 to the ovs br-phy. The mirrored packets are visible at ens1f1 when i capture them using tcpdump. But when i check the flows at br-phy, only few of the packets are arrived.

```
[root@overcloud-hpcomputeovsdpdk-0 ~]# ovs-ofctl dump-flows br-phy
 cookie=0x3435, duration=46778.969s, table=0, n_packets=30807, n_bytes=3889444, priority=0 actions=NORMAL

[root@overcloud-hpcomputeovsdpdk-0 ~]# ovs-ofctl dump-ports br-phy
OFPST_PORT reply (xid=0x2): 3 ports
  port LOCAL: rx pkts=77, bytes=5710, drop=0, errs=0, frame=0, over=0, crc=0
           tx pkts=30107, bytes=3604094, drop=28077, errs=0, coll=0
  port  ens1f1: rx pkts=4385104, bytes=596066321, drop=0, errs=0, frame=0, over=0, crc=0
           tx pkts=33606, bytes=4021526, drop=0, errs=0, coll=0
  port  "patch-tap-bint": rx pkts=30056, bytes=3591859, drop=?, errs=?, frame=?, over=?, crc=?
           tx pkts=739, bytes=294432, drop=?, errs=?, coll=?
```

Any possible reason why im not getting all the packets at ovs bridge br-phy table-0?